# How to fix Error: "Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'" within Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins, yarnpkg

I recently joined a project I am trying to set up a CI server.

I am able to successfully build the software locally when I execute the following from both command line and from terminal window in a MS VS Code project.

```
yarn run build
```

However, when I attempt to run that same command from within a Jenkins build job (Using Windows Command line) I get the following error output: (Note that for now I am running Jenkins on the same machine as my dev environment with successful builds)

```
01:22:35 $ vue-cli-service build
01:22:35 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
01:22:35   throw err;
01:22:35   ^
01:22:35 
01:22:35 Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'
01:22:35 Require stack:
01:22:35 - C:\Users\timju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
01:22:35 - C:\Users\timju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
01:22:35     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
01:22:35     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
01:22:35     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
01:22:35     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
01:22:35     at idToPlugin (C:\Users\timju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:172:14)
01:22:35     at C:\Users\timju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:211:20
01:22:35     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
01:22:35     at Service.resolvePlugins (C:\Users\timju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:198:10)
01:22:35     at new Service (C:\Users\timju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:35:25)
01:22:35     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\timju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js:15:17) {
01:22:35   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
01:22:35   requireStack: [
01:22:35     'C:\\Users\\timju\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-service\\lib\\Service.js',
01:22:35     'C:\\Users\\timju\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-service\\bin\\vue-cli-service.js'
01:22:35   ]
01:22:35 }
01:22:35 error Command failed with exit code 1.
01:22:35 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
01:22:35 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
```

How do I fix this error within Jenkins build environment?

Comment: Are you running `yarn install` before trying to run `yarn build`? If you've [cached](https://dev.to/khsing/speed-up-jenkins-with-npm-build-3pc) the `node_modules` dependencies, it seems it's missing some libs

Comment: not sure why that matters - the build works successfully on command line.  I don't mean to be flippant - I am ignorant of much of the yarn/npm mechanisms

Comment: Sorry, I assumed Jenkins was running on some _other_ machine. Is the job running with the working directory set to your project directory? It seems to be looking in the global NPM directories as opposed to `project_dir/node_modules`

Comment: Oh - That is likely related to the issue - Jenkins is working on its "own" directory structure, not the one I am working on with the dev tools - I will try mucking with that, thanks.